# Content Search Webpart and anonymous users

Tags: web-part, search, anonymous-authentication, cswp

I'm having a Content Search Webpart in my publishing page (SharePoint 2013) searching for contacts in a contact list depending on a field value on the publishing page (field of type managed metadata).

When I'm logged in I get the correct data from the webpart. But this page is for anonymous access and when not logged in all I get is "Sorry, something went wrong" and a Correlation ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (cannot find anything in the ULS log about this message ether).

I do have anonymous access and users can se the page and all its contents (except for the search result). Also the contacts list has anonymous access.

Even more I have set the AnonymousPermMask64 to AnonymousSearchAccessList as suggesting in several blogs.

Anyone having any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround using the Content Query Webpart (still I'd like to find a solution using search...). Here are some of the properties I used in order to get it to work with a managed metadata multiselect field:

```
// list where you do your lookup/search  
<property name="ListName">List Display Name</property>

// if a multi select managed metadata field is used for filtering
<property name="FilterType1">TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti</property>

// your managed metadata field internal name
<property name="FilterField1">field_internal_name</property>

// filter string
// page_field_guid: the managed metadata field guid used to filtering the list
<property name="FilterValue1">[PageFieldValue:<page_field_guid>:<field_internal_name>:TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti]</property>

// if multi select, FilterOperator1 needs to be set to ContainsAny
<property name="FilterOperator1">ContainsAny</property>

// didn't work without this property!
<property name="Filter1IsCustomValue">True</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom display, make sure it has been published. If it has been published, perhaps switch to an OOTB display template (e.g. diagnostic) to troubleshoot.

If you have access to Central Administration, you could also try turning the logging level up to verbose temporarily. Be sure to turn it back down once you grab some logs.

[Configure Diagnostic Logging](http://if%20you%20have%20access%20to%20Central%20Administration.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. My template is already published. Nothing of interest in my logs unfortunately (at least what I could find).